# Passing configuration information to an AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Labmda function which synchronises a remote feed of content to an S3 bucket.  It needs to be run periodically so is currently called hourly using a CloudWatch cron event.

This works great for a single feed, however I now need multiple feeds to be synchronised which can use exactly the same functionality just with a different source URL and bucket.

Rather than clone the entire Lambda function for each feed, is there some mechanism to pass configuration information into the Lambda invocation to specify what it should be operating on?

The function is written in Node 14.x in case that is significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

[image]

In the above image you can start a CRON JOB for **Lambda A** and then it can pass that information as payload using **asynchronous calls** to  **2nd Lambda**.
This will execute the **2nd Lambda** concurrently and thus you can execute as many as **1000** concurrent executions.

It's a fan-out pattern and it can be implemented in your scenario.

**Sample code:**

```
for i in range(3):
  lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='Lambda_B',InvocationType='Event',Payload=json.dumps(payload[i]))
```

Comment: This method looks like it should work, however out of interest would this mean we get double-billed since the parent Lambda would be waiting for the runtime of the longest running 'worker' Lambda?

Comment: @MikeDSutton No, it will be a async call therefore, as soon as Lambda A is done sending all requests to Lambda B, it will end,it will not wait for any response from Lambda B, so no wait time.  Think it like, as soon as the loop of lambda calling ends, it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have 2 options:

In the same function, change environment variables, publish a version, and attach it to ALIAS. Each published version saves its own values for environment variables. With this approach, the problem is if you want to make some change in the code, you would have to re-publish the function for each alias again (and change all the environment variables each time) so this is error-prone.

The second option is to pass the config details through the event param that Lambda accepts (as a JSON) and read in in the Lambda function. You can have separate Cloudwatch events which will pass different JSON event details.

Comment: My preference would be the the latter, but I don't see where the event details can be customised for a CloudWatch cron event?

Comment: @MikeDSutton When you go to edit the event, in the section where you choose the target for the event (you choose Lambda function), there's "Configure input" section. There you can choose either "event" (which in case of cron expression should be date/time) or JSON (where you send your specific JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Trying using Eventbridge cron job which has options to add extra configuration for triggers.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-cron-expressions

Moreover, as per description it seems you want to do action when some operation is performed in S3. Why not trigger lambda on S3 events themselves.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events.html